# Laravel response also contain request payload

Tags: php, json, laravel, response, malformed

when I make request for forget user password api

```
POST /api/forget-password

Route::post('forget-password', [UserApiController::class, 'forgetPassword']);
```

Sample Request

```
{
  "email": "example@gmail.com"
}
```

Expected response

```
{ "message": "success"}
```

Actual response what i getting now is

```
{"email": "example@gmail.com"}{"message": "success"}
```

Controller

```
public function forgetPassword(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::firstWhere('email', $request->email);

    if ($user) {
        $auto_pwd = Str::random(8);

        $hashed_random_password = Hash::make($auto_pwd);
        $user->update([
            'password' => $hashed_random_password,
        ]);

        $this->sendUserCreationEmail($user, $auto_pwd);

        return $this->respondCreateMessageOnly('success');
    } else {
        return $this->respondErrorToken('Enter Correct Email');
    }
}


public function respondCreateMessageOnly($message)
{
    return response()->json([
        // 'code' => Response::HTTP_OK,
        'message' => $message,
    ], 200);
}
```

here is the controller of that route

Laravel version - Laravel Framework 8.8.0

Comment: Could you show your controller or is it external one?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: It's really weird.

Comment: You mean code have some buggy thing? or ?

Comment: I mean I don't see any errors in your code, also I check Laravel files for "response()" helper and I don't see adding request params by default there. Don't know how to help you, try looking for the answer in the web.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. it's not come from Laravel.
The problem has come from docker php-fpm

so I add it to my docker file then working well. my case use: php:8.2-fpm-alpine

RUN sed -i 's/^listen = .*/listen = 127.0.0.1:9000/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

u can refer to it.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80385

Comment: Is it correct that this only applies to specific version(s)?